# How to select all data based on year and month

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, date

I want to select data based on year and month that have chosen by user. But the result doesnt show the correct output. It is just show a list of all data from database.

Can someone help me to fix my code

**VIEW**

```
  <div class="large-3  columns ">
  <?php echo form_open("announcement/announcement_result");?>
  <?php echo form_dropdown('m', $m, set_value('m'), 'id="m"'); ?>
  <?php echo form_dropdown('q', $q, set_value('q'), 'id="q"'); ?>
  <?php echo form_submit('search', 'SEARCH', 'class="button expand"'); ?>
  <?php echo form_close(); ?>
  </div>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
function announcement_list() 
{

  $q = '';
  $data['q'] = $q;

  $this->data['q'] = array(
    '' => ' Select Year',);   

  for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
    {
    $date = date('Y') - $i;
    $data['q'][$date] = $date; 
    }

  $m = '';
    $data['m'] = $m;

    $data['m'] = array(
        '' => 'Select Month',
    );
    for ($m = 1; $m <= 12; $m++) {
        $month = date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $m));
        $data['m'][$month] = $month;
    }

        $data['results'] = $this->news_model->get_announcement_list($config['per_page'], $page);
    }

    public function announcement_result($q='default', $m='default') 
{

    if ($q == '') $q = $this->input->post('q');
    $this->data['q'] = $q;

    if ($q == '') redirect(base_url().'announcement/announcement_list');

    $q = '';
  $data['q'] = $q;

  $this->data['q'] = array(
    '' => ' Select Year',);   

  for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
    {
    $date = date('Y') - $i;
    $data['q'][$date] = $date; 
    }

  $m = '';
    $data['m'] = $m;

    $data['m'] = array(
        '' => 'Select Month',
    );
    for ($m = 1; $m <= 12; $m++) {
        $month = date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $m));
        $data['m'][$month] = $month;
    }

        $data['results'] = $this->news_model->get_results($m, $q, $limit=6, $offset=0); 
    }
```

**MODEL**

```
   function get_results($m ='default', $q='default', $limit, $offset)
{
    $sql = "SELECT *
        FROM ArkibBerita
        WHERE code='PENGUMUMAN' AND Enable = 'Y' AND Lang ='EN' AND BeritaDate LIKE '%$q%' 
        ORDER BY position ASC
        OFFSET {$offset} ROWS
        FETCH NEXT {$limit} ROWS ONlY";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        return $query->result();

}
```

Comment: Instead of  BeritaDate LIKE '%$q%'   use  BeritaDate LIKE '$q%'

Comment: @saurabhkamble my current result is it show list of all announcement from the database which is does not follow the input that have chosen by user. For what i want, the view page will shows list of all announcement, and after search, it will only show data based on year and month. Now, my problem is the search result is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of BeritaDate `LIKE '%$q%' use YEAR(BeritaDate)='{$q}' AND MONTH(BeritaDate)='{$m}`' in your model, I am considering here m as month and q as year from your view

Answer (score 0):

You should check what you send: '%$q%'

```
AND BeritaDate LIKE '%$q%'
```

Please try to echo $sql variable. Then make select an one row from the sql table and compare result for `BeritaDate` field.
I think you sent data in different format, if no result. You should send data exactly as it present into sql table.